# Importar XML no Wordpress corta o endereço do permalink

Tags: php, wordpress, xml

Eu não sei o porquê está assim.

Eu tenho a última versão do XAMPP, e uso o wordpress 4.5.2.
Eu montei um arquivo de xml com todos os posts que preciso importar, mas, quando importo ele corta o meio do endereço do permalink.

No XML a tag '' está assim

```
<link>http://localhost/site/roupas-masculinas/calcas-jeans/desbotados/estilo-cool</link>

<link>http://localhost/site/roupas-masculinas/bermuda-jeans/estampas/estilo-rock</link>
```

Mas quando importo e olho o endereço do post, esta assim

```
http://localhost/site/roupas-masculinasestilo-cool

http://localhost/site/roupas-masculinasestilo-rock
```

Porque ele corta a parte do meio do link quando importo um xml de posts.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema.

No XML para importar, além do campo "link" tem que alterar também o campo "post_name"

Então o campo "link" ficou assim

```
<link>http://localhost/site/roupas-masculinas/calcas-jeans/desbotados/estilo-cool</link>
```

E o campo "post_name" ficou assim:

```
<post_name>roupas-masculinas/calcas-jeans/desbotados/estilo-cool</post_name>
```

Agora o permalink mostra assim

```
http://localhost/site/roupas-masculinascalcas-jeansdesbotadosestilo-cool
```

Ele pega o endereço todo, mas, tira o "/" do endereço.

Se alguém souber como arrumar isto, eu agradeço.